# EpiServer 9 MVC Media not showing up after upload

Tags: model-view-controller, upload, media, episerver

I'm working on an EpiServer site without a template and I have a problem with displaying images on the page. I've created a class that allows me to upload images fine but when i try to display it on the page it doesn't show up in my media folder. Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image]

Here is the code from my class:

```
[ContentType(DisplayName = "ImageFile", GUID = "0b6fe917-9aa6-4e7b-9fae-1ff21a39a614", Description = "")]
[MediaDescriptor(ExtensionString = "jpg,jpeg,jpe,ico,gif,bmp,png")]
public class ImageFile : MediaData
{
    public virtual string Copyright { get; set; }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think you have to show us the code for uploading the images.

Comment: @andreasnico I have added the code from the class above. other than that it's just Episervers standard upload that I'm using

Comment: I'm getting a little confused here. You are talking about "I've created a class that allows me to upload images", but you are doing that through the editmode in Episerver right? So, either you have the wrong file-ending on your image or you have not uploaded it already through episervers editmode.

Comment: btw what happens if you click the "Images" folder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure you inherit **ImageData**, not **MediaData**.

If you use a UIHint of "Image" for a property, the content selector will only display media (files) of types inheriting ImageData.

Comment: This worked perfect! Thank you very much! :D @Ted Nyberg